# javascript: array of variables or separate variables?

Tags: javascript

I used to store variables separately, for example, if I have an old element I would save it in a variable called "ele_old", and then later if I have a new element I would save that in a variable called "ele_new". However, it just occurred to me that I can save the 2 variables in 1 array variable, so I could do something like this:

```
eles_arr['old'] = //old element;
eles_arr['new'] = //new element;
```

this way would allow me to put variables of the same type into the same array for better organization, e.g. elements together in 1 array, and then ids together in another array.

The problem is I am quite new to javascript (and any other programming languages, for that matter), so I'm wondering if this is an inferior way than just keeping each variable separate. Will doing this cause any problems? for example, poor runtime performance?

Thanks!

Comment: What's with the HTML tag between those two JavaScript statements?

Comment: @Sime: I think BigName doesn't know how to format code blocks. I've edited it for him.

Comment: yes, sorry about that. btw, what's the correct way of insert a line break?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is setting properties on the eles_arr object.  It's akin to saying:

```
eles_arr.oldEl = //old element
eles_arr.newEl = //new element
```

It's not storing them in an array, so it's similar to having the variables separated -- they're just grouped in the eles_arr object. To put them in an array you'd do:

```
eles_arr.push(oldEl);
eles_arr.push(newEl);
```

That being said I wouldn't put these two variables in an array.  I would keep them separated to increase readability. It might make sense to you to have the values in the same array, and you may remember their positioning. Other developers may not though, which could lead to problems in the future.

Finally, having an array of two values for 'old' and 'new' will in no way affect performance in your case, but I still would not recommend using an array for readability's sake.

**Update**

I changed the variables from *'old'* and *'new'* to *'oldEl'* and *'newEl'* to reflect Šime's comment on the reserved keyword 'new'.

Comment: `new` is a reserved word. It cannot be used as a property name.

Comment: @Sime: Yeah I was going to mention that, but I kept the property name the same so that he could easily compare the difference between what he had and what I suggested. I'll make the update.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an object to create a namespace / module, and so reduce the number of global / local variables:

```
var eles = {};

eles.foo = document.getElementById("foo");
eles.bar = document.getElementById("bar");
```

But that probably makes sense only if you have like 20 or more elements and you need them in various event handlers / functions. In that case, it makes sense to create the `eles` namespace and populate it with all your element references.